# Python Replace Quoted Values In External SQL Query

Tags: python, sql

I use the simple query below to select from a table based on the date:

```
select * from tbl where date = '2019-10-01'
```

The simple query is part of a much larger query that extracts information from many tables on the same server. I don't have execute access on the server, so I can't install a stored procedure to make my life easier. Instead, I read the query into Python and try to replace certain values inside single quote strings, such as:

```
select * from tbl where date = '<InForceDate>'
```

I use a simple Python function (below) to replace  with another value like 2019-10-01, but the str.replace() function isn't replacing  when I look at the output. However, I tried this with a value like  that wasn't in quotes and it worked.  I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental, but haven't uncovered why it works without quotes and fails with quotes.

Python:

```
def generate_sql(sql_path, inforce_date):
    with open(pd_sql_path, 'r') as sql_file:
        sql_string = sql_file.read()
        sql_final = str.replace(sql_string, r'<InForceDate>', inforce_date)

    return(sql_final)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please do not use string replace/interpolation. It is straight way to SQL Injection. Better way is to use parametrized query.

Comment: Thanks. Totally understand. I’m not concerned with injection at the moment. But I agree with the concern

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error lies in something you didn't show us.  Please provide a [mcve].  Your's isn't complete because we don't have the SQL file.  Also, your function receives a `sql_path` and uses `pd_sql_path`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind folks -- problem solved, but haven't quite figured out why. File encoding is my guess.